# Passing arrays to getopt in Perl

Tags: perl, getopt-long

I am attempting to pass an array to Perl at the command line.

I am reading instructions from https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html

my script is

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use feature 'say';
use autodie ':all';
use Getopt::Long 'GetOptions';

my @array;
GetOptions ("a=s@" => \@array);#'file' indicates string on command line, '=s' means it must be a string
if (defined $array[0]) {#http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Options-with-values
    my @z = split(/,/,join(',',@array));
    say 'The array is ' . join (', ', @z);
}
```

which using the command line outputs

```
con@VB:~/Scripts$ perl array_getopt.pl -a v c d
The array is v
```

which is not correct, as it misses `c` and `d`

I have also tried 
`GetOptions ("a=s" => \@array);` which has the same error.

I see something on that page that says I would have to repeat the same tag over and over like `perl array_getopt.pl -a v -a c -a d`, which the end user won't like.

How can I pass information to the command line so `-a v c d` will pass to an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `s{,}` rather than `s@`. This options is described in `perldoc Getopt::Long`, paragraph [Options with multiple values](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Options-with-multiple-values):

> Options can take multiple values at once, for example
>
> ```
>     --coordinates 52.2 16.4 --rgbcolor 255 255 149
> ```
>
> This can be accomplished by adding a repeat specifier to the option
>   specification. Repeat specifiers are very similar to the {...} repeat
>   specifiers that can be used with regular expression patterns. For
>   example, the above command line would be handled as follows:
>
> ```
>     GetOptions('coordinates=f{2}' => \@coor, 'rgbcolor=i{3}' => \@color);
> ```
>
> The destination for the option must be an array or array reference.
>
> It is also possible to specify the minimal and maximal number of
>   arguments an option takes. foo=s{2,4} indicates an option that takes
>   at least two and at most 4 arguments. foo=s{1,} indicates one or more
>   values; foo:s{,} indicates zero or more option values.

More precisely, using:

```
GetOptions ("a=s{,}" => \@array);
```

in your code does the trick.